# How do i convert to Color to Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, notifications, background-color

I have a color in form of integer, and i want that color to be in a Bitmap form.
Is there any way to do so?

I tried

```
Drawable d = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getbitmap();
```

But the above code give error Cannot cast ColorDrawable to BitmapDrawable

Is there any other way?

**Actual code is**

```
Palette.generateAsync(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(songArt),
            new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGenerated(final Palette palette) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                        Drawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(palette.getDarkVibrantColor(
                                getResources().getColor(R.color.noti_background)));
                        notificationCompat.bigContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.noti_color_bg,
                                ((BitmapDrawable) colorDrawable).getBitmap());
                        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationCompat);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes there is.
You can just do it like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
canvas.drawColor(colorInt)
```

Inside `drawColor()` you can also set the color by using the methods of the `Color` class like `Color.argb(...)` or `Color.rgb(...)`

That way you will have a bitmap with dimensions `width`/`height` and filled with the specified color.

Further explanation: You create a `Bitmap` object with your specified dimensions. Then you create a `Canvas` object and attach the `Bitmap` object to it. This way everything that is drawn using the `Canvas` object methods gets drawn on the `Bitmap` object.

In the end you have a `Bitmap` object with your drawings in it.

Comment: you should only be setting one colour, in the `draw(color)` command... You have wrriten your answer very misleadingly

Comment: edited just wanted to point out various ways to set  a color ssince he is  parsing the color and its an odd way for me to do it like this somehow

Comment: This is a better way of doing what he is trying to achieve in the question.

Comment: he says he has the color integer allready so why parsing from a string?

Comment: @IljaKO its working but the problem is how do i get the height and width?

Comment: do you allready have an existing bitmap? then just use this instead of making a new one. Otherwise its up to you how big you want your bitmap...bitmap class has also methods like getWidth() or getHeight()...ps youre free to mark my answer as correct when it works;)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: @IljaKO everything worked perfect , i stretched the bitmap to fit imageview

Comment: great...did you mean by stretching that you scaled the bitmap?

Comment: you could also just create a bitmap like this when you wan to have it the dimensions of your image view:     Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getWidth(),imageView.getHeight(),Config.ARGB_8888);